# Function pointer to singleton class instance function

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, singleton

What I'm trying to do is create a function pointer to a single class instance function. I want to do this so I can do something like this:

```
C->member_method();
```

instead of:

```
Config::inst()->member_method();
```

but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is my singleton class:

```
class Config {
private:
    Config() {}

    static Config* m_instance;

public:
    ~Config() {}

    static Config* inst() {
        if (m_instance == nullptr) {
            m_instance = new Config;
        }
        return m_instance;
    }

    bool load();
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean just `member_method()`? What's wrong with `Config::instance()->load()`? That's kind of how singletons work.

Comment: Looks like you simply want to create a global variable. You don't even need a pointer. You can just declare `Config C;` at the global scope and be using `C.member_method();`. But it doesn't seem like a terribly good idea.

Comment: Awarded for the most weird design in 2015.

Comment: I was thinking about going the singleton route because I need a global class which contains variables loaded in from a configuration file. From what I've read, there are advantages of using a singleton instead of something like a static object. However, I don't want to call the singleton's methods like `Config::inst()->method_name()` throughout all of my code cus lazy. I guess if there's not a way to do this, I'll just use a static object

Comment: Once you go the singleton way there is no coming back. Your avatar confirm your allegiance to the dark side.

Comment: That class doesnt have to be a singleton. Create a normal class with non static method, create a static instance of the class and voila

Comment: @UmNyobe Doesn't necessarily have to be a `static` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a normal class without static methods, ditch the singleton pattern aside, and create an instance.

The burden of singleton pattern [usually outweigh any benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: I think im going to follow your advice. I don't fully understand the singleton pattern and what I need is fairly straight forward / simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static class method for a facade, to let you use your preferred syntax:

```
class Config {

    // The declarations you already have, then:

public:

    static void member_method()
    {
        inst()->member_method_impl();
    }
private:
    void member_method_impl();
};
```

Then, simply invoke:

```
Config::member_method();
```

If you just want to use a class pointer-like syntax, you don't need to declare anything. Just use:

```
auto C=Config::inst();
```

then:

```
C->member_method();
```

Comment: guaranteed "wtf" generator.